# Visual basic error "Variable is used before...."

Tags: vb.net

Please help me! I wrote the following program, there are a mistake "Variable "arr" is used before..." I tried to fix, but I couldn't. Please help me:) Thanks a lot!

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO

Class Test
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Try
            ' Create an instance of StreamReader to read from a file.
            Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader("a.txt")
            Dim line As String
            Dim arr()() As Char
            Dim tem As Integer
            tem = 1
            ' Read and display the lines from the file until the end 
            ' of the file is reached.
            Do
                line = sr.ReadLine()
                arr(tem) = line.ToCharArray
                Console.WriteLine(Line)
            Loop Until line Is Nothing
            sr.Close()
        Catch E As Exception
            ' Let the user know what went wrong.
            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:")
            Console.WriteLine(E.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Test.Main()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Used before what? Do you understand what the error means?

Comment: Note that you've just (poorly) re-invented `File.ReadAllLines()`.

Comment: Warning 1 Variable 'arr' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime. And I understand but I couldnt find the way to fix it

Comment: Could you please show me how to correct it? I have just learnt it myself:(

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the `arr` variable.

Since you don't know how big the array needs to be, you should use a `List(Of T)` instead.